# javafx: ComboBox get the "original" selecting event

Tags: events, select, javafx, combobox

i'm using a Popup within a Combobox to achieve something like a text completition:

```
Popup popup=new Popup();

ObservableList<String>  items=FXCollections.observableArrayList("Abba","Baltimore","Chinatown");
ComboBox combo= new ComboBox(items);

combo.getSelectionModel().select(0);
combo.setStyle("-fx-font-size:"+table_font_size);


popup.getContent().addAll(combo);
popup.setAutoHide(true);
popup.show(primaryStage);


combo.show();
```

This shows an **expanded** combobox.
Now i want that it is closing, when the user select something.
By selecting i mean two ways to do this:

- Click on an item by mouse
- Use the arrow keys and then press "ENTER" to make the selection

I tried:

```
combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { 

     //completition stuff goes here              

     popup.hide();
}
```

The problem here is, that it works,when i use the mouse, but not with the arrows,because it immediatly close after pressing.

Comment: Since you're already implementing the popup yourself, it would probably make more sense to use a `ListView` in the popup, instead of a `ComboBox`. Then register mouse listeners with the cells of the list view, and a key listener (to listen for enter) with the list view (or maybe popup).

Comment: This would lead to another problem: how to resize the ListView that it fits to the items...

Comment: Ah,I can see that might be tricky. But you can do the same thing even if you use a combo box, no? Register the mouse handler with the cells, etc.

Comment: The combobox resizes just fine by magic ;-)

Comment: Oh man,it was so easy like 1 2 3: combo.showingProperty().addListener(e->{popup.hide();});